# Is there any way to bypass Google proxy block in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I'm making an app (using Selenium webdriver in Chrome) that searches Google for a specified query (`http://www.google.com/search?query`) but everytime I search for it I want to change my IP so I'm using proxies.

The problem is Google blocks EVERY proxy I use. Is there anyway to bypass it? Maybe I'm using wrong type of proxies? (I've tried HTTP and HTTPS proxies, still they get blocked everytime)

Maybe my code is wrong?:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
options.add_argument("disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server=ip:port")

driver = Chrome(options=options, executable_path="C:/WebDriver/bin/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.google.com/search?query")
```

Can it be a matter of the proxies quality?

Answer (score 0):

Google has removed the proxy support for FTP entirely in Google Chrome versions 76 and newer. You can use firefox or edge. I tried with firefox and able to launch:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe"
options.add_argument("disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server=ip:port")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'..\drivers\geckodriver.exe', options=options)
```

**Import:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
```

Comment: Still the same Google blocks my request and tells me to do the captcha...